# I want background of my cocos2d game to be the view of the camera of iphone. How do i do that?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am making a game with augmented reality in it. So, i want to have the camera view as the background of the game. However, I am finding some difficulties in doing this.

I tried doing it using the UIImagePickerController but then when i do that, all i get is the camera view and the game elements disappear.

I looked at some of the articles..

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1752

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/711

but i didnt get any proper answer and it only confused me more.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/introduction-to-augmented-reality-on-the-iphone

Comment: yea i found it myslvs only. anywyz thnx!